# Not to add spring-security.xml in web.xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

To achieve security in my web application, I provide below the snippet in web.xml apart from filter DelegatingFilterProxy. Is it possible to encapsulate the spring-security xml configuration file inside a module like inside a resource folder in maven based project.

I do not want to add the following in **web.xml** .

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/spring-security.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

I provide below the snippet of spring-security.xml file

```
<security:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
        <!-- <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDao"> -->
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="user" password="user"
                    authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                <security:user name="xyz" password="xyz"
                    authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                <security:user name="abcd" password="abcd"
                    authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </security:user-service>
            <!-- <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"></security:password-encoder> -->
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
```

Please help me in this regard. The objective is to only add DelegatingFilterProxy in web.xml and security module as a jar file.